# Jenkins: choose among different deployment methods (Master slave vs ansible)

Tags: jenkins, ansible, jenkins-pipeline, devops

I have three **VMs** which I have used to deploy develop, staging and master branch of a project.

Lets say jenkins is running on **VM** named **JEN**

- Develop branch on **VM** named **DEV**
- Staging branch on **VM** named **STAGE**
- And Master branch on **VM** named **MASTER**

I have made three slave node (**DEV**, **STAGE**, **MASTER**) on Jenkins and thee different branch's ***Jenkinsfile*** run on different VMs(**DEV**, **STAGE**, **MASTER**).

Another approch I am coming through is:

- Not to make **DEV, STAGE, MASTER** as slave node. That is we have only one Jenkins Agent (**JEN**).
- Run pipeline and the tests in it  on **JEN** and use ***ANSIBLE*** to deploy remotely on (**DEV, STAGE, MASTER**)

How would that compare with the first approach?

Answer (score 0):

First, I believe it is **[Ansible](https://www.ansible.com/)**, not ancible.

Second, the interest of an Ansible deployment model is that is is **agentless** (as opposed to Jenkins, which needs an agent listener `agent.jar`)

So if what you need to deploy is *not* the sources but deliverables, Ansible is more suited for that task, provided the target machines are accessible through SSH.

The Jenkins pipeline would simply do a **[`tower_cli`](https://tower-cli.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)** call to the right Ansible Job Template: that is what I have in my deployment platform.